# Oracle 18c & .Net 4.7.2: "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client could not be loaded"

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-6

In my .NET 4.7.2 class library project, I added the "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" nuget package. When accessing the DbContext

```
using (var ctx = new BdeDbContext())
```

I am getting "The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application."

After looking at similar posts, I also added the "ODAC for Visual Studio 2017" and "odp.net.x64", but that didn't help. Did anyone have similar problems?

My app.config looks like follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v13.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.122.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.18.3" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="CommonServiceLocator" publicKeyToken="489b6accfaf20ef0" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.4.0" newVersion="2.0.4.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL.MYCOMPANY.COM))) " />
            </dataSources>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BdeDb" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=sys;Password=0r@cl3;Data Source=orcl.mycompany.com" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The relevant project references are:

- EntityFramework
- EntityFramework.SqlServer
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

Comment: Why do you use the Oracle.DataAccess and the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess ? There is no reason for this. Perhaps you mixed it up somewhere.

Comment: It was just another try to get the problem solved. It didn't work already before installing it. I removed the package again now. The error stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the data access logic in a separate project, installing the Oracle DataAccess nuget package also in my main project solved the problem. Looking closer to the error message helped ... ;)

> "and that the assembly is available to the running application"

Comment: I think you don't have to install the "full" package. Just the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` file should be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me to fix ODT with Visual Studio:

1. In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options
2. You should find Oracle Developer Tools, if not reinstall ODT
3. Open Oracle Developer Tools, click General
4. This will magically wake up ODT to complete its installation

Running Visual Studio 2019.